# Asterisk or venv/* in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

What should I leave in .gitignore inside of venv file in order to not keep track when using `git add *`.

I am a bit confused because just asterisk is used inside of original .gitignore, but I saw suggestions like adding venv/* or even venv/

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the venv directory by adding `venv/` to your .gitignore. There is a Github repository dedicated to .gitignore, [(git repository)](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Python.gitignore), so I would highly suggest checking that out.

Comment: should I still use git add* if I am not adding asterisk?

Comment: Nope. You just need to do 'git add .' It'll take into consideration the .gitignore. If you want to check if it worked, just do 'git  status'

Comment: `git add *` will generally be noisy (telling you that it's not adding venv files, but that you *can*, if you want to, if you add the `-f` option) while `git add .` will be quiet, so `git add .` is *nicer*. But both will work.